# 36ft pole from the ground then adding 7.80 meters antenna on top is this legal

Tags: antenna, legal, europe

If I use a 36ft pole and a 7.80 meters antenna on top of the pole, is this going to break the law in Scotland?

My antenna that I'm planning to install is a siro 827.

Comment: No doubt this isn't a question that will have a yes or no answer given how councils and local governments interact.  More stakeholders == more complications. What has your research shown? Surely, some guidelines are published by various branches of government at the national level?

Comment: For example, is https://www.ofcom.org.uk the overseeing body for Scotland? They seem to publish guidelines for antenna use. Then you might have to see what your local government and neighbours have to say.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!